# ng-click doesn't work with btn element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an ng-click event on btn element and it doesn't work at all.
I don't know why is the reason for that.
Here is the code

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller('mainCTRL',function($scope){
  $scope.clickme = function(){
    console.log("click-me");
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app"  ng-controller="mainCTRL">
<h3><a href="#/NEI">NEI</a>
<btn class="btn btn-link" ng-click="clickme"><i class="mprest-icon mprest-icon-assistance"></i>Assistant</btn>
</h3>
</div>
```

am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `ng-click="clickme()"`, You have missed `()` Closing question as TYPO

Comment: Check [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/kXYG8YMeESJ7vfa4VEDX?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

change for that clickme():

```
<btn class="btn btn-link" ng-click="clickme()"><i class="mprest-icon mprest-icon-assistance"></i>Assistant</btn>
```